# Error: OpenCV: Overflow for image Size

Tags: c#, wpf, emgucv

I am trying to use my camera through the EmguCv library. Following their documentation, I am doing the following:

```
Capture capture = new Capture()
Mat frame = new Mat();
capture.Retrieve(frame, 0);

image1.Source = BitSourceConvert.ToBitmapSource(frame.ToImage<Bgr, Byte>(););
```

However the last line continually throws the following error: **OpenCV: Overflow for image Size**

My private static BitSourceConvert Class is copied directly from their info [page](http://www.emgu.com/wiki/index.php/WPF_in_CSharp).

Doing the following also throws an error:

```
Image<Bgr, Byte> = capture.QueryFrame().ToImage<bgr, Byte>
```

Could someone provide me an example on how to load and save an image?

I am using EmguCv version 3.1

Thank you.

Comment: did you find answer? i am struck with same problem. could you please tell me the solution